# Make a constructor parameter into a template parameter

Tags: c++, boost, idioms

I have a home-brew ring buffer class like this:

```
template<typename T, int maxElements>
class RingBuffer
{
};

class Foo
{
    RingBuffer<int, 2000> ring;
};
```

This is a performance bottleneck, as a quick replacement with `boost::circular_buffer` showed a 7% saving in the overall code. However, I need to explicitly construct the `boost::circular_buffer` like this:

```
class Foo
{
    boost::circular_buffer<int> ring;
public:
    Foo() : ring(2000) {}
};
```

Is there a neat idiom (or indeed another Boost template!) that I can wrap `boost::circular_buffer` with to say something like:

```
class Foo
{
    auto_construct<boost::circular_buffer<int>, 2000> ring;
};
```

So I no longer need to touch the `Foo::Foo()`?

**Update**: Although in-class initialisers get close, I also have `typedef`s:

```
using Ring200 = RingBuffer<int, 2000>;
```

So I would like:

```
using BoostRing2000 = auto_construct<boost::circular_buffer<int>, 2000>;
```

So that I don't need to remember the `{2000}` every time I declare one.

Comment: Do in-class initializers qualify as "not touch the `Foo::Foo()`"? I mean `struct Foo { boost::circular_buffer<int> ring{2000}; };`.

Comment: I'd forgotten that feature, and that's getting close, but let me update my question as I have `typedef`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use in-class initializers with a non-type template parameter for your `Foo` wrapper.

```
template <std::size_t N> struct Foo {
   boost::circular_buffer<int> ring{N};
};
```

And the appropriate type alias would be

```
using BoostRing2000 = Foo<2000>;
```

If it's desired to keep the actual type of the data stored flexible, you can add another template parameter such that

```
template <class T, std::size_t N> struct Foo {
   boost::circular_buffer<T> ring{N};
};
```

which allows for fine grained control over the type aliases, e.g.

```
using BoostIntRing2000 = Foo<int, 200>;
template <class T> using BoostRing2000 = Foo<T, 200>;
```

and the instantiations now read

```
BoostIntRing2000 someIntegerRing;
BoostRing2000<double> someDoubleRing;
```

Comment: I think your should generalize it to accept any `T`. But otherwise have an upvote :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I though about it, too, but then decided to let `Foo` encapsulate the type to give it more meaning than just avoiding the constructor call. But being kind of convinced, I'll add this option to the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

A default member initializer can do.

```
class Foo
{
    boost::circular_buffer<int> ring{2000};
};
```

Assuming your intent is to only touch the member definition. It also carries the advantage that if you ever change your mind for a specific constructor, it's not a hassle to modify. Just add a member initializer to that c'tor and your'e done.

---

Given the edit, I'm unfamiliar with anything in `boost` the can do what you are after. But another approach, that will also save you some substitution, is to implement your homebrewed `RingBuffer` as a thin wrapper around `boost::circular_buffer`.

```
template<typename T, int maxElements>
class RingBuffer : boost::circular_buffer<T> // Can also be a member instead of privately inherited
{
  // Now pull what we need with using delcarations and define a c'tor

   public:

   RingBuffer() : boost::circular_buffer<T>(maxElements) {}
};
```